# jquery file input and Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: jquery

I am trying to take file input using a button and hidden input. I don't know what's wrong and it's not working and showing me the error. Can anyone help me please?

```js
$(".fileinput-button").click(function() {
  $(".fileinput").click();
})
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg fileinput-button">
  <div class="row_1">Choose file</div>
  <p class="row_2">from your computer</p>
  <input class="fileinput" type="file" style="visibility: hidden; width: 1px; height: 1px; position: absolute;" multiple="">
</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your click event handler causes a click event which is caught by the click event handler which causes a click event which is caught by..... quick answer: move the `input` outside of the `button` - that's invalid HTML anyway. Also, don't put block level elements, ie the `p` and `div` inside a `button` and use a separate CSS file for your styling rules. Don't put them in a `style` attribute in your HTML, it's a violation of the separation of concerns principle.

Comment: Hey, Thank you very much it really solved my issue. But I was just not getting what the problem was going on there.